# Is the use of the reflexive pronoun 'herself' incorrect here?

Tags: grammar

"Mordaunt has lost her commanding lead, with herself, Truss and Badenoch now all effectively tied in their head to heads."

Should the subject pronoun 'she' be used instead of the reflexive 'herself'?

Mordaunt has lost her commanding lead, with she, Truss and Badenoch now all effectively tied in their head to heads.

Edit: thanks for your replies. Could 'her' be used instead of 'herself'?

Comment: This is going to be flagged/closed as proofreading unless you include some details of why you think using a reflexive pronoun could be a problem here.

Comment: Absolutely not *she*, because in "with she/her/herself tied", *tied* is not a finite verb but a past participle acting adjectivally.

Comment: The fact you set that off with commas is a bit awkward. That said, simple research would show that a subject pronoun (she) is *never* preceded by a preposition.